# my function is called and what is inside it is ran, but then i get `undefined` on the console

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am learning `react native`. For the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  highlight() {
    console.log(111111111);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(222222);
    console.log(this.highlight());
    console.log(333333);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>sdsd</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I get this output at the console:

```
2222222
111111111
undefined
33333333
```

and `sdsd` on the device screen. what is that `undefined` for?? if it is `undefined` how it ran the log inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in render() you are wanting to log what highlight() returns.
But highlight doesn't return anything it does its own logging.

So render should look like this:

```
render() {
    console.log(222222);
    this.highlight();
    console.log(333333);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>sdsd</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(this.highlight());
```

Prints out the return of `this.highlight()`, but `this.highlight()` doesn't return anything.

Either return the value from `this.highlight()` and print it at the call site, or just write `this.highlight()`.